# Is there a way to restrict the key values in an array object from repeating

Tags: typescript

The type should detect if the array has duplicate items and throw error in typescript?

```
// formType
type formType = Array<{
  key: Here string type is required and guaranteed to be unique;
}>

const a: formType = [
  {
    key:"a1",//repeat
  },
  {
    key:"a1",//repeat
  }
];//error

const b: formType = [
  {
    key:"a1",//no repeat
  },
  {
    key:"a2",//no repeat
  }
];//success
```

Can this be done?
Do I need to define a new type to wrap around object or define a new type for key?

Comment: Short answer is no, I don't believe this sort of typing exists in any language. I don't even think this is a type definition, but rather a property of the array. I assume this is just checking the values of a predefined array, and you want to catch duplicates before runtime. So you could just add this uniqueness check as a unit test.